# Greek Characters in Doxygen Documentation

Tags: html, c, documentation, doxygen, doxywizard

I need to briefly discuss some math in my code documentation and I'd like to insert an actual
Greek letter (lower-case lambda) rather than using the word "lambda." How can I do this in Doxygen? I've only dabbled in HTML with a 500-foot pole once before (I'm by no means a web programmer), so please forgive my ignorance. I've tried placing an `&lambda` in the documentation like the Doxygen user manual mentions, but it was unfortunately taken literally.

======================= Edit =======================================================

Here's the example as requested:

```
/**
 *     This function is used to fill an array with exponentially distributed
 *     random numbers. These numbers are distributed assuming rate parameter
 *     (&lambda;) = 1.
 *
 *     The output vector can be modified for an arbitrary &lambda; by dividing
 *     its contents by the desired value of &lambda; (or, preferably for speed,
 *     multiplying its contents by the precomputed value of 1/&lambda;) as
 *     shown in the histogram below.
 *     @image html exponential_histogram.png
 *
 *          @param size The size of the array to be filled.
 *
 *          @param vector The array which the user wants to fill with random
 *          values. Again, it should be of type @b float.
 *
 *          @param state The array which was initialized with the
 *          "DSP_urand32_init" function and maintained (but @b NEVER modified)
 *          by the user between subsequent calls to this function.
 */
```

Comment: I know nothing about Doxygen, but regarding HTML, a correct reference for lambda is `&lambda;` with the semicolon, and omitting the semicolon may cause the string to be taken literally. But primarily, can’t you just use “λ” as such (with due consideration of character encoding issues)?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I added the semicolon...unfortunately, no dice. Now I get a literal `&lambda;` instead

Comment: Just checked. It is working fine for me, so you must be doing something wrong; like using a too old version of doxygen, or putting the &lambda; at an unexpected place. Please provide an example.

Comment: Well it's certainly not the version since I'm using 1.8.4. But I will provide an example momentarily.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the table of maintainer of various languages: [Support for multiple languages](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/langhowto.html)

You can find your language and contact the maintainer (you'll see the address).

Answer (score 0):

In version 1.9.1 you can encode symbols by simply use the html notation.

```
namespace sample
{
   /// @brief sample to show &pi;
   class Show
   {

      public:
         /// @brief Show as as sample
         Show();
         ~Show();
   };
}
```

And it will generate π directly in your document

Comment: That's nice, but in the original question and comments it is explicitly stated that the HTML entity notation `&lambda;` did *not* work.

Comment: In the original question stated that version 1.8.4 was used and here the `&lamda;` already worked (as did the `&pi;`). In doxygen version 1.8.1 it didn't work but as off 1.8.2 it does.

Comment: You both are right, I did edit, to explicit say that it works in version 1.9.1 just in case someone else (like me) ends in this question for newer versions